# How to measure multi-label multi-class accuracy

Tags: accuracy, auc, f1score

I have a model that has multi-label multi-class targets

Example

| Age | Height | Weight | Mark | Distance | Red | Yellow | Green | Blue | Black | White |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 160 | 62 | 78 | 103 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 56 | 177 | 90 | 99 | 363 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 32 | 179 | 79 | 83 | 737 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 17 | 180 | 94 | 75 | 360 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 43 | 186 | 102 | 51 | 525 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 55 | 168 | 74 | 48 | 644 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 18 | 182 | 93 | 58 | 127 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Target values are the colours (Red, Yellow, Blue Green, White Black)

when I build my model and test different measures

I get F1 score of 0.78

but I get very low accuracy 0.03

Why is that big difference? and which measure shall I use?

Answer (score 1):

It's either multi-label or multiclass classification, not both. This case is multi-label classification: zero, one or several labels for every instance.

You didn't say how you obtain these scores so it's difficult to know what's going wrong but these scores are not consistent. My guess would be that the accuracy is not calculated properly, possibly because the function is not called with the right arguments. Keep in mind that both F1-score and accuracy evaluate binary classification, by themselves they cannot account for multi-label.

Technically multi-label classification with $n$ labels is equivalent to $n$ independent binary classifiers, one for every label. Thus the first level of evaluation is for every independent binary classifier. Then these scores can be aggregated in different ways.